# Is the four-velocity always normalized?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, velocity, conventions

In the book i have reading defines the [four-velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity) like $$U^\mu=dx^\mu/d\tau.$$ The metric used is $\eta_{\mu\nu}=diag(-1,1,1,1)$. It is straightforward to show that the norm of the four-velocity is normalized,
$$\eta_{\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu=\eta_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=-c^2$$ since, we have defined the proper time as
$$c^2d\tau^2=-ds^2=-\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu.$$

My question is, what happens in the case of other more general curved metrics $g_{\mu\nu}$? Is still the norm of the four-velocity equal to $-c^2$? Or $-1$ if we put $c=1$?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167690/2451

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but it is more general than this. The norm of any 4-vector is invariant under arbitrary coordinate transformations in any spacetime. So showing that it is always equal to -1 in one coordinate system shows that it is equal to -1 in any coordinate system.

Comment: Just to clarify, not every 4-vector necessarily has norm -1 (such as the 4-momentum). However, every 4-vector norm is indeed invariant in the way you said. In particular, the 4-vecloity has norm -1 in a locally Minkowski frame, so it has norm -1 in any coordinate system.

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: there is a difference between the norm of every four-vector and that of the 4-velocity. Both are invariant under coordinate transformations, but the latter is invariant along a geodesic as well.

Answer (score 4):

I have realized that indeed, the norm always be $-1$ under these considerations above. Because the definition of proper time $d\tau^2$.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a general curved metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, the four-velocity $U^\mu$ is defined as
$$U^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau},$$
where $\tau$ is the proper time along the particle's worldline. The proper time is defined by
$$d\tau^2=-ds^2=-g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu.$$
The normalization condition of the four-velocity is
$$g_{\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu=-c^2.$$
Note that the normalization constant can be different from $-c^2$ depending on the choice of units.

To see why this is true, consider the interval between two nearby events along the particle's worldline. This interval is given by
$$ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu.$$
If we choose the coordinate system such that the particle is at rest at the origin, then the interval reduces to
$$ds^2=g_{00}dt^2,$$
where $t$ is the coordinate time. The proper time elapsed between the two events is given by
$$d\tau^2=-ds^2=-g_{00}dt^2,$$
so $d\tau/dt=\sqrt{-g_{00}}$. Therefore, the four-velocity is
$$U^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}=\frac{dt}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\mu}{dt}=(\sqrt{-g_{00}},0,0,0),$$
which satisfies the normalization condition
$$g_{\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu=-g_{00}=-c^2.$$

In summary, the normalization condition for the four-velocity depends on the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, and it is given by $g_{\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu=-c^2$ (or $-1$ if we use natural units $c=1$).

Comment: I think that your definition of the proper time would be multiplied by -1

Comment: Thank you for pointing the mistake, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using the geodesic equation (which describes the change of $U^\mu$), we also obtain the term $g_{\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu$ being constant:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\tau}(g_{\mu\nu}U^\mu U^\nu)
=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\tau}(g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu)
&=\left(\partial_\xi g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\xi\right)\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu
+g_{\mu\nu}\ddot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu
+g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu\ddot{x}^\nu \\
&=(\partial_\xi g_{\mu\nu})\dot{x}^\xi\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu
-g_{\mu\nu}\left(\Gamma_{\kappa\lambda}^\mu\dot{x}^\kappa\dot{x}^\lambda\right) \dot{x}^\nu
-g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu\left(\Gamma_{\kappa\lambda}^\nu\dot{x}^\kappa\dot{x}^\lambda\right) \\
&=(\partial_\xi g_{\mu\nu})\dot{x}^\xi\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu
-\left(g_{\mu\nu}\Gamma_{\kappa\lambda}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu
+g_{\mu\nu}\Gamma_{\kappa\lambda}^\nu\dot{x}^\mu\right)\dot{x}^\kappa\dot{x}^\lambda \\
&=(\partial_\xi g_{\mu\nu})\dot{x}^\xi\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu
-2\Gamma_{\xi\kappa\lambda}\dot{x}^\xi\dot{x}^\kappa\dot{x}^\lambda \\
&=(\partial_\xi g_{\mu\nu})\dot{x}^\xi\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu
-(\partial_\kappa g_{\xi\lambda})\dot{x}^\xi\dot{x}^\kappa\dot{x}^\lambda
=0.
\end{align*}
For the last step, recall the definition:
$$\Gamma_{\xi\kappa\lambda}
=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\kappa g_{\xi\lambda}
+\partial_\lambda g_{\xi\kappa}
-\partial_\xi g_{\kappa\lambda}),$$
in which the last two terms together are antisymmetric in swapping $\xi$ and $\lambda$, so applying $\dot{x}^\xi\dot{x}^\lambda$ makes them vanish.

Comment: Not every particle follows a geodesic, and consequently not every trajectory satisfies the geodesic equation. The normalization of the four-velocity is due to the possibility of choosing locally inertial coordinates, where the norm of the four-velocity is by construction normalized.